# How do I convert this jquery to pure javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, checked, oncheckedchanged

Hello I want to convert the following to pure JS if possible.

My ultimate goal is to display the var "bar" if checkboxes with id's ("checkbox1", "checkbox2", "checkbox3") are selected + display corresponding id's ("item1", "item2", "item3").

```
$('input:checkbox').change(function () {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        switch (this.id){
            case 'checkbox1':
                bar.show();
                item1.show();
                break;
            case 'checkbox2':
                bar.show();
                item2.show();
                break;
            case 'checkbox3':
                bar.show();
                item3.show();
                break;
            default:
                bar.hide();
        }
    } else {
        bar.hide();
    }
});
```

How can i simply do this?

Comment: Add the HTML too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code example.

```js
const ids = ["item1", "item2", "item3"]

document.addEventListener("change", function(event) {
  if (event.target.matches('input[type="checkbox"]')) {
    const checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]')
    let checked = []
    
    checkboxes.forEach(function (cb) {
      if (cb.checked) checked.push(cb)
    })
      
    const checkedIds = checked.map(cb => cb.id)
    
    if (isSubArray(ids, checkedIds)) {
      document.querySelector("#var").style.display = "block"
    } else  {
      document.querySelector("#var").style.display = "none"
    }
    
    document.querySelector("#cb-ids").innerHTML = checkedIds
  }
})

function isSubArray(arr1, arr2) {
  return arr1.every( el => arr2.includes(el))
}
```

```html
<p id="var" style="display: none">var</p>

<p id="cb-ids"></p>

<label for="item1"> 
  <input id="item1" type="checkbox" />
   Item 1 
<label/>
<label for="item2"> 
  <input id="item2" type="checkbox" />
   Item 2 
<label/>
<label for="item3"> 
  <input id="item3" type="checkbox" />
   Item 3
<label/>
<label for="item4"> 
  <input id="item4" type="checkbox" />
   Item 4
<label/>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. In order to select an HTML element, you can use the `document` class methods (e.g. [`document.getElementsByTagName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByTagName)).
2. As written in [jQuery's documentation](https://api.jquery.com/show/), `show()` and `hide()` actually modify the `display` attribute of an HTML element.

Comment: thanks for your answer! I do want to move away from jQuery and want to write everything with pure JS. Is that possible with css pseudo classes? And what would the if/else statement look like?